# Why would Docker Desktop unpause itself in Windows 11

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

Given:
Docker Desktop (latest version) Version 4.19.0 (106363)
Windows 11 Pro 22H2

When I pause Docker Desktop, after a few minutes it will unpause itself. Anyone know why this might happen?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know why it happens, on Windows 10 I'm running into the same problem.

But I found a workaround that may help you.

Entering `docker pause [CONTAINER] [CONTAINERS] ...` in my terminal does work and the processes won't unpause themselves then.

So I made an alias in my ~/.zshrc for the following command:

`docker pause $(docker ps -q | tr '\n' ' ')`

this pauses all docker containers. And to unpause:

`docker unpause $(docker ps -q | tr '\n' ' ')`

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hello, this doesn't quite answer the question, maybe ou should have posted another one with this answer instead.